# Google Sheets time and currency calculations issue

Tags: google-sheets, time, currency, calculation

In Google Sheets, is there a way to multiply time values with currency values? Current result doesn't work.

In other words,

Multiply hours(A) * dollars(B), result display in dollars(C)
[image]

What's the syntax to write this kind of matching?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the total number of hours in `B2` by using a combination of [DAYS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296) (for the number of full days passed, which you have to multiply by 24 to get the hours) and [HOUR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093045) (for the hours passed in the last -nonfull- day):

```
DAYS(B2,)*24+HOUR(B2)
```

Then you can multiply that by `B4`:

```
=(DAYS(B2,)*24+HOUR(B2))*B4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(B2)*B4, "$0.00")
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me the exact same outcome. It seems like I need to multiply the time value by 24 before I can calculate further

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "Hours later than 6pm" should be a number and not a time value.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated: I was looking to get an output in Dollars for a time and currency multiplication. Here is what I came up with hope it helps others who come here looking for the same.

```
=TEXT((D2*24)*40,"$0.00")
```

[Currency*Time Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2QFv.png)